# react-dom.production.min.js:189 TypeError: o.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern, web-development-server

code working in development but not working in production.
when i uploaded on vercel its not working.
this is error ->

```js
react-dom.production.min.js:189 TypeError: o.map is not a function
    at gd (Home.jsx:31:15)
    at xo (react-dom.production.min.js:167:137)
    at Cu (react-dom.production.min.js:197:258)
    at Es (react-dom.production.min.js:292:88)
    at bc (react-dom.production.min.js:280:389)
    at gc (react-dom.production.min.js:280:320)
    at mc (react-dom.production.min.js:280:180)
    at ac (react-dom.production.min.js:271:88)
    at ic (react-dom.production.min.js:268:429)
    at w (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)
du @ react-dom.production.min.js:189
```

**map function code**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Card from "../components/Card";
import axios from "axios";
const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`;
const Home = ({ type }) => {
  const [Videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchVideos = async () => {
      // const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/videos/${type}`);
      const res = await axios.get(`/videos/${type}`);
      setVideos(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
      console.log(typeof res.data);
    };
    fetchVideos();
  }, [type]);

  return (
    <Container>
      {/* {Array.from(videos)
        ? Array.from(videos).map((video) => (
            <Card key={video._id} video={video} />
          ))
        : null} */}
      {/* {Array.from(Videos).map((video) => (
        <Card key={video._id} video={video} />
      ))} */}
      {Videos.map((video) => (
        <Card key={video._id} video={video} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

i am just want to fix this issue. i am not able to deploy this code on host because when i deploy on host its give error after deploy on site.

localhost is running good without error